# Apache: A lot of connections gracefully finishing?

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, apache-traffic-server

at the moment I'm mentioning that a lot of connections are `gracefully finishing` if I visit my apache2 status-page.

What does that mean and why are they gracefully finishing? Some of them are in this state for 5-10min.

The server uses `Apache 2.4` with `event-worker` and `PHP-FPM` as PHP-handler.

[image: Gracefully finishing]

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with a few PHP scripts and finally resolved it. I had written a script to close and release the browser connection but continue processing the script. The problem was my script was timing out (because it was doing a time-intensive activity) causing the connection to be stuck in "Gracefully finishing." My PHP was doing some third party API calls via a loop in a script and so in the loop I just kept resetting the PHP time limit within the loop (set_time_limit()).

Answer (score -1):

What value do you have set for MaxConnectionsPerChild? I've found that when this is too low, and the processes restart, this is what causes those Gs.

Comment: It will cause a G for that process while restarting but not to hang indefinitely in that state.